# How to send encrypted text from node js and decrypt in typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, firebase, encryption

I am making firebase cloud function in node.js inside `index.js` file as,

```
exports.calculatePrice = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    cors(request, response, () => {
         var fare = 10; 
         response.send(request.query.distance * fare);
    })
});
```

Here `response.send(request.query.distance * fare)` is the calculation for total fare based on the distance travelled and fare..

Here i need to send this `response.send(request.query.distance * fare)` as secure data and need to receive it in typescript as,

```
let distance = 20;
this.http.get('https://us-central1-sample-project.cloudfunctions.net/calculatePrice/?distance=' + distance).subscribe(data => {
    this.finalFare = data;
})
```

I also need to send the `distance` with encrypted in typescript and get the encrypted value and need to make decrypted in `node js`..

In simple while fetching the data in `this.http.get(https://us-central1-sample-......)` in which i need to pass the encrypted distance and need to get it in `index.js` and after calculation of total fare was done need to send back the total fare with encryption and need to get the total fare in `home.ts` (typescript file) decrypted and assigned to `this.finalFare = data`..

I have tried the below in `index.js` inside `calculatePrice` function by importing `crypto`,

```
var salt = crypto.randomBytes(128).toString('base64');
var iterations = 10000;
var hash = pbkdf2(String(request.query.distance * fare), salt, iterations);

response.send(hash).
```

But it doesn't work..

I hope even it would be better to replace the word encrypt and decrypt (which i have used in this question) with sending and receiving the secure data (which is all i am in the need)..

Please help me to send and receive the data securely from node js to typescript (for calculated total price) and also from typescript to node js (for distance)..

Comment: `pbkdf2` is made to produce slow salted hash intended for passwords, there is no way to recover original value. To pass data to the backend - wouldn't SSL do the job?

Comment: @gusto2, I am new in this scenario,so please help me in the right way to achieve fetching of values securely..

Comment: The idea is you should use `https` to pass data, so far you gave no reason to encrypt anything on the client side that couldn't be achieved by simply using https

Comment: @gusto2, Can you elaborate little in clear.. I thought it could be achieved in the client side and hence not given reason.. But i am beginner and so i am not sure about how to achieve it of sending encrypted values from typescript to node js (for distance) and vice versa (for price calculation)..

Answer (score 0):

```
var hash = pbkdf2(String(request.query.distance * fare), salt, iterations);
```

This is a hash, it's a one way function, usually used to store and validate passwords without being able to gain the original plain value.

In theory - you may encrypt the data on the client-side (typescript) e.g.using [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) or [Window.crypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/crypto).  For that you need to share the encryption key with the server (nodejs) securely which is not easy task. TLS (https) will do it for you.

> I also need to send the distance with encrypted in typescript and get the encrypted value and need to make decrypted in node js.. 
>   Please help me to send and receive the data securely from node js to typescript (for calculated total price) and also from typescript to node js (for distance)..

As far I understood your goal is ensure confidential transport of data between components, client and server-side operation.

As already told, using **https** ensures sending data through an encrypted channel. It's transparent - you just send/receive normal plain values, but the traffic itself is securely encrypted. Just make sure the communicated endpoints are using https protocol ( e.g. `https://us-central1-sample-..`) .

As well the client can be sure it talks to the correct server. Still - you need to ensure the data sent to the server (nodejs) are from the correct client. I believe The simplest option for you is using simple user authentication.

Long story short - using https (sending / receiving data) will ensure the values are sent over an encrypted channel when used properly.